# What is the difference between 「中止」and 「停止」?

Tags: words

In my dictionary app, they both translate to "suspension".

What is the difference between 「中止」and 「停止」?

Comment: I need to do more research to find definitive proof but teishi seems closer to suspend (temporary) and chuushi to stop permanently or call off a plan. Also, teishi can be used for physical objects while chuushi can't, as far as I'm aware

Answer (score 3, accepted):

中止 is when something is cancelled. Like a concert being cancelled due to bad weather. 停止 is when something is stopped. Like a train being stopped due to mechanical issues.

Comment: So which is correct: 「クラウドサービス一時提供中止」 or 「クラウドサービス一時提供停止」 and why?

Comment: ポーランドは１２０年間国家として存在を停止した。
Poland ceased to exist as a nation for 120 years. (Tangorin) teishi doesn't have to mean come to a physical stop.

Comment: @macraf: 「クラウドサービス一時提供中止」でも意味は理解できまし、このように表現している人も結構います。私もこれでもいいかと思います。しかし、「中止」と「停止」の意味を考えると、「クラウドサービス一時提供停止」の方が正しいのだろうと思います。「停止」はすでに実施していることをやめる（再開するかどうかは別にして）ことですが、「中止」は計画はしていたが一度も実施しないでやめることです。しかも、一般に今後実施することはない。macrafさんが検討対象として挙げたフレーズに「一時」とありますので、既に実施していることが分かります。従って「停止」の方がいいのでしょう。但し、「停止」は車やモーターの動きのように、実際に動いているものに対して使うニュアンスが強いので、「クラウドサービス」に使うとやや違和感があります。従って「クラウドサービス一時提供停止」も駄目なように思います。従って最初に挙げたように、「クラウドサービス一時提供中止」という表現が使われるのかもしれません。「一時提供中止」が駄目、「一時提供停止」も駄目なら、「クラウドサービスの提供を一時中断します」のような表現の方が良いのかなと思います。

Comment: @macraf I think クラウドサービスの一時停止 implies stop providing the service for now but couple of weeks later they will start providing the service. Whereas クラウドサービスの一時中止 implies they stop and might consider if they provide the same service again. It’s ambiguous though.

Comment: @kimiTanaka I think 一時 unequivocally indicates that in either case it is not permanent. So I don’t understand your explanation.

Comment: @macraf Thanks. If I borrowed mackygoo’s クラウドサービスの提供一時中断, it make more sense to me.

Comment: @mackygoo その「中止」の定義には同意できません。野球で7回裏で大雨コールドゲームになったら、それは停止や中断ではなくて中止です。また、「サービスの一時提供停止」という表現は、個人的には何の違和感もありません。

Comment: @naruto:確かにnarutoさんの例にあるように、既に開始したアクションでも「中止」という場合があることは分かりました。従って、先のコメントで私が示した「中止」の定義は少し変更が必要ですね。ところで、「サービスの一時提供停止」と言う表現に対する感想は個人の感性の範疇ですので議論は致しません。